# Binomial expansion, where is the mistake?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I attacked the [Question](http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Mathematics%20(9709)/9709_s14_qp_11.pdf)
and the [marking scheme](http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Mathematics%20(9709)/9709_s14_ms_11.pdf)
Question 3.

---

**Question**
Find the term independent of $x$ in the series expansion of $$\left(4x^3+\frac1{2x}\right)^8$$

---

First I expanded inside the bracked, then took the 2x out and got:
$$\dfrac{1}{256x^8}(4x^4+1)^8$$
Now from here we can see that we get $x^8$ when $(4x^4)$ will be on the power of 2, which is at $8C6$
Now that will be:
$$8C6(\dfrac{1}{256x^8})(4x^4)^2$$ which is
$$28*16x^8(\dfrac{1}{256x^8})$$
which will be $$\dfrac{7}{4}$$
but the marking scheme shows just 7. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Those are both marking schemes aren't they?

Comment: @JohnDoe My bad, edited

Comment: Also, in future, could you please type up the question here, rather than making people go find it in a document? :)

Comment: Your mistake is, when you factored out the $2x$, the $4x^3$ becomes $8x^4$ not $4x^4$.

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, sorry. Ahh, I even wrote it as $$8x^4$$ for the first time on paper, then changed it to 4... thank you

Answer (score 2):

When you took $2x$ out, it would be $$\frac{1}{256x^8}(8x^4+1)^8$$ instead of $$\dfrac{1}{256x^8}(4x^4+1)^8$$

Now, your answer will be multiplied by a factor of$2^2$ which will finally give the answer to be $7$.

Answer (score 0):

The binomial expansion will have a constant term when the powers of $x$
$$
\left( 4x^3\right)^{p} \left( \frac{1}{2x} \right)^{q} 
$$
total to $0$. That is
$$
x^{3p-q} = x^{0}.
$$
Therefore
$$
q = 3p.
\tag{1}
$$
Each term in the binomial expansion has order 8. Using Pascal's triangle
$$
 \left( 4x^{3} \right)^{8} + 
8 \left( 4x^{3} \right)^{7}\left( \frac{1}{2x} \right)^{1} +
\color{blue}{28 \left( 4x^{3} \right)^{6} \left( \frac{1}{2x} \right)^{2}} + \dots
$$
In other words,
$$
 p + q = 8
\tag{2}
$$
Which values of $p$ and $q$ satisfy (1) and (2)?
$$
 p =2, \quad q = 6.
$$
This is $\color{blue}{blue}$ term in the expansion:
$$
\boxed{
\color{blue}{28 \left( 4x^{3} \right)^{6} \left( \frac{1}{2x} \right)^{2}} = 28 \frac{16}{64} = 7
}
$$

---

Pascal's triangle
[image: pascal's triangle]

Comment: $$28 \frac{16}{64} =7 \neq \frac{1}{7}$$